# How to change the camera's position in LibGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I would like to know why my `OrthographicCamera` doesn't move. Here is the code I used:

```
world.getPlayer().setX(world.getPlayer().getX()-0.05f);
camera.position.set(camera.position.x-0.5f, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
camera.update();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your render method have you set your camera projection matrix to combined.

```
 batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);//batch is the name of the spritebatch
```

Comment: If I do like you told, the textures are extremely big.

Comment: @Venji It's because before you where not drawing with that camera. in other words the `SpriteBatch` used the screen pixels to draw too. Once you set it's projections matrix to `camera.combined` it will use the camera. You either need to make the `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` of the camera larger or draw your textures in a smaller area of your world.